# How do I create a dictionary with arrays as the object?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class MyClass {

    var lists = Dictionary<String, Any>()

    init(){
        lists["lobby"] = [Int]()
        lists["events"] = [Int]()
        lists["missed"] = [Int]()
    }


    func isInsideList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool{ //whichList could be "lobby", "events", or "missed"
        //check if "id" is inside the specified array?
       if let theList = lists[whichList] as? Array {  //this throws an error
           if theList.contains(id) ......
       }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Indeed... the whole point of the `if-let-as?` is to attempt something that might fail and **not** throw an error if it does...

Comment: Replace Array with [AnyObject]

Comment: "Ambigous reference to member subscript"

Comment: Also, perhaps you would like to define your method as `func isInsideList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool`

Comment: @NicolasMiari yes :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func isInsideList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool {

```
if let theList = lists[whichList] as? [Int] {  

  if theList.contains(id) {

        return true
    }
}

return false
```

}

Comment: How do I append to this list? It says "Any?" has no member "append"

Comment: var str = "Hello, playground"

var lists = [String : AnyObject]()


lists["lobby"] = [1,3,4,5,6]
lists["events"] = [3,6,78,8]
lists["missed"] = [0,9,9,9,9,9]


func isInsideList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool{ //whichList could be "lobby", "events", or "missed"
    //check if "id" is inside the specified array?
    if let theList = lists[whichList] as? [Int] {  //this throws an error
        if theList.contains(id) {
            
            return true
        }
    }
    
    return false
}

isInsideList(6, whichList: "lobby")

Answer (score 0):

If you can opt to typecast the dictionary, do so, like the following:

```
var lists = Dictionary<String, [Int]>()

lists["lobby"] = [Int]()
lists["events"] = [Int]()
lists["missed"] = [Int]()


func isInsideList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool{
    //whichList could be "lobby", "events", or "missed"
    //check if "id" is inside the specified array?
    if let theList = lists[whichList] {
        for (var i = 0; i < theList.count; i++){
            if (id == theList[i]){
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

However, if you require that your dictionary contains an array of possibly various kinds of objects, then you can do the following:

```
var anyList = Dictionary<String, Array<AnyObject?>>()

anyList["lobby"] = [String]()
anyList["events"] = [String]()
anyList["missed"] = [String]()

func isInsideAnyList(id: Int, whichList: String) -> Bool{
    // Attempt to get the list, if it exists
    if let theList = anyList[whichList] {

        // Loop through each element of the list
        for (var i = 0; i < theList.count; i++){
            // Perform type cast checks on each element, not on the array itself
            if (String(id) == theList[i] as? String){
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```